# Relation of norms of matrices

Tags: matrices, functional-analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces

Let $A$ be $m \times n$ matrix. Let $B=\frac 1n AA^*$, where $A^*$ is a transposed matrix. Let $X_i, I\leq m$ be row-vectors of $A$.
Show
$$
\|B\|=\frac 1n \|A\|^2\geq \max_{i\leq m}|X_i|,
$$
Where, $\|C\|=\sup_{|x|=1}|Cx|$ is an operator norm of matrix $C$.

Remark:

For above equation:I know that for any two operators $S, T$, we have $\|ST\|\leq \|S\|\|T\|$. How to show that $\|AA^*\|=\|A\|\|A^*\|$?

For the inequality: I would use definition of the operator norm of $A$ and choose vector $x=(1/\sqrt n, \ldots, 1/\sqrt n)$, but it did not work...

Comment: If you let $A= {1 \over 2}$, then the inequality above does not hold.

Comment: What do you mean by $A=\frac 12$?

Comment: A $1 \times 1$ matrix whose value is ${1 \over 2}$.

Answer (score 1):

For the equality: as you noted, $\|ST\|\le\|S\|\,\|T\|$ for all $S,T$, so we only need to show $\|AA^\ast\| \ge \|A\|\,\|A^\ast\|$.  Here we go:
$$
\|A^\ast x\|^2
= \langle A^\ast x,A^\ast x\rangle
= \langle x,AA^\ast x\rangle
\le \|x\|\,\|AA^\ast x\|
\le \|AA^\ast\|\,\|x\|^2
$$
Dividing by $\|x\|^2$ and taking the supremum over nonzero $x$ yields $\|A^\ast\|^2 \le \|AA^\ast\|$.  Since $\|A\|=\|A^\ast\|$, we're done.

For the inequality: As noted in comments, something seems to be wrong here.  (The inequality isn't homogeneous: replacing $A$ with $\lambda A$ changes the LHS by $\lambda^2$ but the RHS by $\lambda$.)  Could there be a typo?